# How to return the right class for a queried child entity in a Joined Inheritance?

Tags: class, inheritance, doctrine-orm, symfony4

I tried to implements a [class table inheritance](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#class-table-inheritance) for my application.

My parent class is User and I have few child classes (like Employee, Customer...). I managed to get it to work with authentication but I have a class type problem :

- If I query for a User who is an Employee, it returns me an Employee (GOOD)
- If I query for all Users it returns me a mixed-bags of child classes (GOOD)
- If I query for an Employee it returns me a User (PROBLEM)
- If I query for all Employees it returns me Users (PROBLEM)

Is this an expected behavior or am I missing something ?

I tried querying the EmployeeRepository directly but it still returns me an User.

I guess I could get Users through the UserRepository with the id returned from the EmployeeRepository but this seems wrong to me

I could also change the EmployeeRepository to append to all queryBuilder a "WHERE user INSTANCE OF App\Entity\Employee" but it feel like this should be the default behavior ?

User entity :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="roles", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"ROLE_USER" = "User", "ROLE_EMPLOYEE" = "Employee", "ROLE_ADMIN" = "Admin", "ROLE_CUSTOMER" = "Customer", "ROLE_RESELLER" = "Reseller"})
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"username"}, message="There is already an account with this username")
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;
```

Employee entity :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\EmployeeRepository")
 */
class Employee extends User
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    private $hideCompetitors;
```

Employee repository

```
/**
 * @method Employee|null find($id, $lockMode = null, $lockVersion = null)
 * @method Employee|null findOneBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null)
 * @method Employee[]    findAll()
 * @method Employee[]    findBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null, $limit = null, $offset = null)
 */
class EmployeeRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    public function __construct(RegistryInterface $registry)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, Employee::class);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the database, the Employee I was trying to fetch had his entry in his table but his role (DiscriminatorColumn) in User was incorrect (ROLE_USER).